# does it need to release MAPIOBJECT in outlook object model?

Tags: outlook-redemption

here i am running separate task using redemption inside a outlook plugin.

Does mapi MAPIOBJECT is com object and does it needs to release as following ? 
what happen if i release mapi object ?

```
  public async Task SimpleTask(string entryId)
    {   
                 RDOMail rdoMail = null;
                 RDOSession rdoSession = null; 
                 try
                 {
                     var outlookApp = addinModule.OutlookApp;
                     var outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                     var mapiObject = outlookNamespace.MAPIOBJECT;
                     rdoSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();

                     if (rdoSession != null)
                     {
                         rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = mapiObject;
                         bool loggedOn = rdoSession.LoggedOn;                     

                         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryId))
                         {
                             rdoMail = rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(entryId);
                             //...;
                             rdoMail.Save();
                         }
                     }
                 } 
                 catch (System.Exception ex)
                 {

                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     rdoMail.ReleaseComObject()
                     mapiObject.ReleaseComObject();
                     rdoSession.ReleaseComObject();
                     outlookNamespace.ReleaseComObject();
                 }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a COM object. OOM represents it as `IUnknown`. It is `IMAPISession` (derived from IUnknown).